# Getting this crash in Salesforce MobilePush SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush

I'm getting the following fatal exception reported from the ET SDK, is there something I can do to avoid this happening?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;.<init>
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.a$a.(SourceFile)
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.m.a(SourceFile:53)
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.configureSdk(SourceFile:290)
       at gbis.gbandroid.Application.onCreate(SourceFile:109)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Don't expect anyone to help you if you just post the error message and nothing else.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs Well what should i post here this is plain Exact target crash from Exact Target Sdk, I am seeing this crash in crashlytics it is happening to my app users out in the wild.

Comment: Actually Adam, I work on this product and I know exactly what the problem is.  This question, like half-a-dozen others in the past few weeks keeps getting incorrectly flagged.  Please unflag this message as the error is perfectly clear and the resolution is known.

Comment: @bill you are saying the resolution is known, Can you please tell what exactly is the resolution for this

Comment: I've reopened this. @ManasPrasher, when posting please try to phrase things as a question, I suspect this got quickly closed because it was nothing more than a crash dump.

Comment: @ManasPrasher can you please provide all of the dependencies in your `app/build.gradle`?